# Does "the purple planet" have a real name?

Tags: star-wars, the-clone-wars

It appeared in Star Wars: Clone Wars "chapter 22" and was named "[the purple planet](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Purple_planet)" due to its purplish hue.

The planet was used as a [battle site](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Battle_of_purple_planet) between the Confederacy of Independent Systems and the Galactic Republic during the Clone Wars, so I would assume that after battling on a planet, they may have given it a more meaningful name?

Comment: It seems that Star Wars wiki does not have a name for it besides _Purple planet_.

Comment: Perhaps Planet Nexium?

Comment: @MattGutting any references on this?

Comment: @SaturnsEye "Nexium" is an acid reflux medicine commonly called the Purple Pill. Matt was making a joke.

Comment: @S.Fruggiero *face palm*

Answer (score 4):

This planet appears to be [Xagobah](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Xagobah), a fungal world. Wookieepedia describes it at "shrouded in purplish mists...caused by spores and pollen."

**Boba Fett: A New Threat**, by Elizabeth Hand relates the battle from Fett's perspective as he attempts to collect a bounty on CIS leader Wat Tambor who is fortified inside a bioengineered fortress termed ["Mazariyan"](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Mazariyan).

Comment: interesting, but the Wookiepedia image doesn't look very.. purple

Comment: @SaturnsEye - wookiepedia is notoriously inaccurare. Why would the colors there be? :)